# Why isn't selenium successfully clicking my download link?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to use selenium to download an excel file from a website. I am not sure why the code isn't allowing me to download it. I get an exit code 0 so everything ran successfully but I am not seeing the file in my downloads.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



def scrape_mclellan_website():
    url = 'https://www.mcoscillator.com/market_breadth_data/'
    s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

    driver.get(url)
    download_link = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="data_table"]/a[1]/img')
    download_link.click()

scrape_mclellan_website()
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in normal (not headless) mode and watching what happens?

Comment: yes- the behavior is the same

Comment: Did you try clicking the anchor not the img? `value='//*[@id="data_table"]/a[1]'` - without headless mode.

Comment: QHarr both have the link embedded in it. good catch tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to fix?

Wait until the element you try to click is present and click the `<a>` not the `<img>`:

```
download_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="data_table"]/a[1]')))
download_link.click()
```

Set your preferences for donwload folder and take care window is opening in right size:

```
prefs = {'download.default_directory':'ENTER PATH TO DOWNLOAD FOLDER'}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
```

#### Example (selenium 4)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

service = Service(executable_path='ENTER YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER')
prefs = {'download.default_directory':'ENTER PATH TO DOWNLOAD FOLDER'}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.mcoscillator.com/market_breadth_data/')

download_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="data_table"]/a[1]')))
download_link.click()
```

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this- the solution is to add time.sleep(1) to the script. Seemed to do the trick. I tried the solution by HedgeHog and was not able to replicate his fix, but it got me thinking that the browser was just closing before the download could be initiated. Ill mark it as correct because it got me close enough. Also- the img and the text both had the download link.